# C#: Restore Window executing same exe

Tags: c#, system-tray, remote-process

I execute my Program, which later displays a Form. Once I minimize it, it gets shrinked into the systemtray. Doubleclicking my systemtray-icon does:

```
Show();
Activate();
WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

Which shows the Form again. Works.

**Question:**
How can this be done while executing the same exe again, instead of doubleclicking the trayicon?

**Problem:**
ShowWindow(handle, SW_MAX) displays the window, but some elements in the form are missing. 
*NOTE:* This does not happen, when i doubleclick the tray-icon.

Answer (score 0):

this will be helpful , you can find the current process is running or not when you re executing the process, if running you can maximize the current process [Link](http://www.codelocker.net/30367/dot-net-c-sharp-find-a-process-and-maximize-or-minimize-all-process-windows/)

Comment: window is now maximised, but some elements in the form do not get displayed. Why can that be?